os.walk best approach for making dirs and extracting .zip file into the newly made dirs
Suppose I have a root directory with n number of project folders inside it. Each project folder contains one .zip file with 2 files in it: dpd.zip and lib.ear.
I want to write a script that if I put it inside the root folder, the script will iterate over all of the projects directories and inside each of the project will create a new directory named "core" with 2 sub directories named "zip" and "ear" and then, the script will extract .zip file in the projects directory, move the dpd.zip and lib.ear into each relevant sub folder that was created, and finally extract the contents and delete itself after the job was done.
What I have tried so far:
import os
import shutil
import zipfile

def extract_zip(file_path, extract_to):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(extract_to)
    
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for subdir in dirs:
        if not os.path.isdir(subdir + "core"):
            core_dir = subdir + "/core"
            ear_dir = core_dir + "/ear"
            zip_dir = core_dir + "/zip"
        
            os.mkdir(core_dir)
            os.mkdir(ear_dir)
            os.mkdir(zip_dir)
        
            # so far the tree was made inside each project`s folder
        
            for fl in os.listdir(subdir):
                file_path = os.path.join(subdir, fl)
                
                if fl.endswith(".zip") and os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    extract_zip(file_path, core_dir)
                    # so far extract the core .zip into the core folder of each project`s
                
                    # here comes the obstacle
        else:
            continue

The obstacle is when I try to add logic and keep the extraction of the .zip and .ear into its relative subdirs. The only solution I came so far was opening another for loop specific for the core subdir`s, and add logic for the files in it (.zip/.ear/other files), extract and remove the extracted source. But, because the root folder contains a huge number of projects, this solution is not efficient and will last forever to complete.
Do you think there is a walk-around here?
Thanks in advance for your support.
Update:
The final tree should look like:
root/
    Project1/
        core/
            zip/
                # extracted files from dpd.zip
            ear/
                # extracted files from lib.ear
        # extracted files from core without .zip .ear extension files
    .
    .
    .

    ProjectN/
        core/
            zip/
                # extracted files from dpd.zip
            ear/
                # extracted files from lib.ear
            # extracted files from core without .zip .ear extension files


...and finally extract the contents and delete itself after the job was done - Can you elaborate on this? Do you mean that dpd.zip should be extracted and deleted?

Do no over-optimize (or better wrongly optimize). zip files should always extracted in a empty directory (security reasons, and this rule should be written in many places in documentation). On many operating systems moving file (within a file system) is extremely fast: just adding a name in the directory, content is not touched). -- So you can do elaborate logic, handle better overwriting files, etc.): good tools must have good error message, so you must do a lot of manual work, but it is worth the extra efford

@MilosStojanovic yes exactly. Initial state: Project folder + core.zip file(core.zip contains lib.ear and dpd.zip). Final state: Project folder + core folder (inside it there will be 2 folders zip and ear and each of these will have the extracted data from dpd.zip and lib.ear approproately). At the final state there should be no .zip/.ear files left in the Project`s tree.

Why do you need to "move the dpd.zip and lib.ear into each relevant sub folder"?

@SIGHUP good question. Further, I will make some transformation and package back all the changes to the initial state.

@Caveira but you said "..there should be no .zip/.ear files left in the Project`s tree"

@SIGHUP thats exactly what I said. At the end, if I will extract the zip and ear into the same folder, make changes and then zip back to zip and ear, then it will mess all the things up because how it will know if the files belong to zip or ear in original?

@Caveira I'm more confused now. What are extracted files from core without .zip .ear extension files? Can you please give initial state and final state with file examples.

Much of what you need to do is simplified when you use the pathlib module which is, after all, the "modern" way.
Your explanation isn't entirely clear but I think this will do what you need.
Also uses multithreading which may enhance performance.
from pathlib import Path
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from collections.abc import Iterator
from zipfile import ZipFile

def extract_and_remove(s: Path, t: Path):
    with ZipFile(s) as z:
        z.extractall(t)
    s.unlink()

def process(d: Path):
    for file in d.glob("*.zip"): # should only be one zip file
        extract_and_remove(file, d)
        e = d / "lib.ear"
        z = d / "dpd.zip"
        if e.exists() and z.exists():
            core = d / "core"
            for f, target in [(e, core / "ear"), (z, core / "zip")]:
                target.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                extract_and_remove(f, target)


def directories(root: Path) -> Iterator:
    for entry in root.glob("*"):
        if entry.is_dir():
            yield entry

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # specify the root directory here
    root = Path("root")
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
        exe.map(process, directories(root))


What should be passed as root? Should it be . or absolute path or something else? It's not working for me when I replace it with what I said (at least not with initial state as I provided in my answer). Am I doing something wrong?

@MilosStojanovic The "root" is wherever you want it to be. The code doesn't change directory so it could be either relative or absolute. Perhaps, for the elimination of doubt, use an absolute pathname then you could add some debugging to show exactly what you're dealing with. Of course, I may have misunderstood the question. After all, it is rather ambiguous

But if ear.exists() and zip.exists(): will be False since those files have to be extracted first from .zip file that is in project folder.

@MilosStojanovic Looks like I misread the OP. Code edited accordingly
